# How to upgrade application for business user?

Tags: installation, automatic-updates

We have WPF application which is created in .NET4.0. We have upgraded our application to .NET4.5 with a new version.
Now, we are getting problem to install upgraded software in user's system. There are few thousands user using our app. It will take time and need human effort to install s/w in each and evryone's system.

Is there any automatic tool which can help us in deployment? How managesoft is working?

Regards,
Ambarish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used clickonce (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to deliver our WPF application, and all the related dependencies. It worked quite well, even with frequent automated upgrades.

Comment: This is not usable for our system. Our system is dependent on C:\AppFolder  which store exe and all required dlls. So, we have to make windows installer. Is there any way to make windows installer automatic?

Comment: Storing a program in a fixed folder is not a very good decision.. what if the user does not have a C: drive? :)
Of course, you can make a window installer, which can also handle upgrade; it will not be that easy though. We used both the installer generated by VS2008 and WiX (several years ago, now) and it was not pleasant. Maybe they got better now..